# SUM Array using IF AND

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to get a `SUM` function to check both the month and a check of Y or N to return a total.

Currently I am using the array formula `=SUM(IF(MONTH(A8:A1000)=1,C8:C1000,0))` to do the month check, however I can't get the `AND` function to work in there. I am trying to get it to check column E for a Y mark in order to return the `SUM` as well.

Any help would be lovely.

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

1. Nest another `IF` condition in your array formula rather than using `AND`.

   > =SUM(IF(MONTH(A8:A1000)=1,IF(E8:E1000="Y",C8:C1000,0),0))

   This option requires array entry of the formula (i.e., enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Use `SUMPRODUCT` with the two conditions built into an argument.

   > =SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A8:A1000)=1)*(E8:E1000="Y"),C8:C1000)

   This option does not require array entry.

Comment: I almost always prefer the `SUMPRODUCT` solution over the array formula. It's usually shorter, easier to follow and edit, and less likely to break because I forgot to use `CTRL`+`SHIFT`